# Constraint errors after logging in through Google Auth

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-authentication

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding why I'm getting a bunch of constraint errors that reference views in my loginViewController, after I successfully log in via Google Auth and just as I segue to my rootViewController from my loginViewController.

If I'm just using a mail/password auth, I don't get any errors, but when I use Google Auth, it throws a bunch of constraint errors even though it still segues successfully. Any insight on what might be causing this behavior?

```
Google user is signed in Optional("B4ffsdfdstWvet2WXlcv2")
2020-06-28 21:12:03.326165-0400 Effortflex[82238:3461439] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010ad6d0 UIStackView:0x7fb691e0f3a0.top == UILayoutGuide:0x600000af9260'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top + 580   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010ad770 UIStackView:0x7fb691e0f3a0.bottom == UIStackView:0x7fb691e0abd0.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001090d20 UILabel:0x7fb691c09940'OR'.height == 25   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010adae0 UIStackView:0x7fb691e0abd0.bottom == GIDSignInButton.top   (active, names: GIDSignInButton:0x7fb691d0e360 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010adbd0 GIDSignInButton.bottom == UILayoutGuide:0x600000af9260'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom - 20   (active, names: GIDSignInButton:0x7fb691d0e360 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010aec10 'buttonHeight - auto generated by GIDSignInButton' GIDSignInButton.height == 48   (active, names: GIDSignInButton:0x7fb691d0e360 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010ae4e0 'UISV-alignment' UIView:0x7fb691d0bcc0.centerY == UILabel:0x7fb691c09940'OR'.centerY   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010ae350 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[_UILayoutSpacer:0x600000c92c10'UISV-alignment-spanner']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fb691e0abd0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010ae3a0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fb691e0abd0.centerY == UIView:0x7fb691d0bcc0.centerY   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010ae8a0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fb691e0f3a0.top == UIButton:0x7fb691d0c6c0'LOG IN'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010ae8f0 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UIButton:0x7fb691d0d9e0'SIGN UP']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fb691e0f3a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010ae990 'UISV-fill-equally' UIButton:0x7fb691d0d9e0'SIGN UP'.height == UIButton:0x7fb691d0c6c0'LOG IN'.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010ae940 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIButton:0x7fb691d0c6c0'LOG IN']-(20)-[UIButton:0x7fb691d0d9e0'SIGN UP']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010ae210 'UISV-spanning-boundary' _UILayoutSpacer:0x600000c92c10'UISV-alignment-spanner'.bottom >= UILabel:0x7fb691c09940'OR'.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010aecb0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7fb691d19af0.height == 808   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010ad4a0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-bottom' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x600000af9260'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(34)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fb691d19af0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010ad3b0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-top' V:|-(88)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600000af9260'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fb691d19af0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001090d20 UILabel:0x7fb691c09940'OR'.height == 25   (active)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all of the identifiers and view controllers are called correctly. This can happen if there are typos. Also be sure to check that all of your segues are connected to the right items and that you've not accidentally added conflicting or multiple of them to the same items.